# Display account name on alert

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to get the name of Account as alert in visualforce page. I tried getting name of the user using below code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="Accounts" sidebar="False" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Website}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.NumberOfEmployees}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Details">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Details" onClick="alert('{!$User.FirstName}')"/></apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Can anyone help me displaying Name of the Account on alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `onClick="alert('{!a.name}')"` instead of `onClick="alert('{!$User.FirstName}')"`.

Comment: Thanks that's working :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try like this for picklist, but you need the include jquery library

**Like This:**

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jquery}"/>
```

**Below Code VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="DoesntMatterBro" standardStylesheets="false">
```

```
     <apex:selectList id="SelectedVal" value="{!Name}" size="1">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"/>
     </apex:selectList>
     <apex:commandButton action="{!null}" reRender="noneurvey" value="Save" id="theButton"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

**Below code Jquery:**

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            jQuery("[id$='SelectedVal']").addClass('SelectedVal');
            jQuery("[name$='body']").addClass('jumbotron');
            $(document).on("click", "[id$=theButton]", function() {

                a = $('.SelectedVal').val();
                alert(a);

           });     
        });
    </script>
```